# Mongo export query

Tags: mongodb

I am doing regex command

mongoexport --host localhost --db testml75spectredb_UK_IRE --collection peoplecollec_UK_IRE --type=csv --out /home/ubuntu/production2.csv -f full_name,headline,linkedin_id,given_name,family_name,url,num_connections,industry,locality,experience.0.organization.0.name -q '{ "headline" : { $regex: / php| javascript| js | ios | android| ruby| rubyonrail| java| laravel| scala| python| django| nodejs| node.js| angularjs| angular.js| devops| fullstack| fullstack| full-stack| C++| C#| WPF| J2EE| golang| objective-c| swift| .NET| reactjs| react.js| backbonejs| backbone.js| .js |symfony2| zend| pyramid| ASP.NET| python| java/i}}'

cause iM looking with people having one of this word in their headline and I have a tons of non relevant document

Comment: What is the pattern or word you're looking to match? and are you trying to match to the string above?

Comment: In my file I am having so many fields for headline when I execute that query I need to get the fields mentioned in the headline..         Yes i need the strings that I mentioned in the regex as headline